# Fluid simulation isn't fluent

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

I am working on an closup of fluid animation but fluid movement is quite jerky. I need a nice fluent movement. Is it possible?

[video](https://youtu.be/beSCOEZLGBI)

My settings

[image]

Comment: You need a lot higher domain resolution and also higher fps.

Comment: I tried 300 resolution and 50fps and it is better. Thank you :)